# How to make R to read full data in CSV file, instead of a partial of it?

Tags: r

R for Win 3.6.1 / RStudio / Miktex 2.9 (all are latest versions) installed on a 4G RAM laptop (i5) / 12G RAM desktop(AMD Phenom)/ 16G RAM desktop (Ryzen 5 2600).

I ran a onclass code to read csv file (the code as below attached) but could only read a partial of the full data (26,116 rows of 44,000 around in total, with 16 variables read among the total 18 variables).  Checked with the professor and confirmed the code is correct, other students ran the same code well, but on my 3 PCs the results are the same.  The professor and I haven't figured out the reason.

```
la <- read.csv('https://douglas2.s3.amazonaws.com/data/LA.csv', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Uninstalled the existing 3 softwares (R, RStudio, Miktex), restarted before reinstall the latest versions of them; Download the file to local disk and read.csv from local disk.

```
la <- read.csv('https://douglas2.s3.amazonaws.com/data/LA.csv', stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Expected result: Read the full size data of the file (about 44,000 rows and 18 columns) Actual result now: Can only read 26,116 rows and 16 columns on 3 different PCs with (4G/12G/16G RAM). Other peers (students on class) have no such a problem (codes are same - distributed directly by the professor).

Comment: using `fread()` from `library(data.table)` resulted in 44620 rows and 16 columns for me. after manually downloading the file and inspecting it, i am only seeing 16 columns.

Comment: `la <- read.csv('https://douglas2.s3.amazonaws.com/data/LA.csv', stringsAsFactors=F)` loads 44620 rows and 16 columns for me with no problem in R 3.5.

Comment: Are you sure there is even 18 columns? There is 44620 rows but I also get 16 columns.

Comment: How are you checking the size of the data after you read it in? What does `sessionInfo()` show (especially the locale part)? When i read the file i see 44,620 rows and 16 columns. The amount of RAM should have nothing to do with this problem. You would get an error if it can't read all the data, R won't just stop reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question to the answer space)*.

Sorry for my mistake - Yes, it is a 16 columns dataframe, not 18.  Sorry! :-D
I used read_csv and I could read the full 44000+ rows.  However, I can't do that no matter How I tried on my win10 1903 (may2019 version) laptop and desktops - one is MacAir, the other 2 desktops are AMD systems.

The interesting point is that, when I switched back to (dual systems) MacOS and installed R, RStudio & Mactex (same "components") on that, the problem disappeared - I can easily and much much much faster (almost immediate) to get the full rows read into the environment.  That's so mysteroius.

So, I feel that the problem has no relationship to hardwares (both Intel & AMD systems were tested).  The only clue perhaps is the newly upgraded Win10 1903 version.  Since on MacOS, nothing is abnormal.  Strange.

Accordingly, I stick to MacOS when I am handling R class in this term.  I was almost purchasing a new Thinkpad X1 Carbon due to the problem.  My last trial within MacOS saved me $1,500+.